# Send SMS without presentViewController

Tags: swift, sms

Is it possible to use Swift to send an SMS without having to use `presentViewController`? I want to press a button and have it send an SMS.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
messageVC.body = "MESSAGE"
messageVC.recipients = [phoneNumber]
messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self

self.presentViewController(messageVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I really doubt it's possible as it would have a huge potential for abuse (e.g., SMS to premium rate numbers.)

Comment: The only thing you can do is send the message from a server. But then you have to pay for the costs